# How do I perform bulk replacement of objects?

Tags: c#

Imagine a factory that produces objects of a certain type but keeps a `WeakReference` to them. This factory can tell us how many objects of a particular type are alive. But what if I want to replace every single one of those objects with an entirely different instance, but have every single location in code where this instance is used be automatically updated. How do I do it?

For example, given the following scenario:

```
public interface ITheme
{
  string TextColor { get; }
  string BgrColor { get; }
}

class LightTheme : ITheme
{
  public string TextColor => "black";
  public string BgrColor => "white";
}

class DarkTheme : ITheme
{
  public string TextColor => "white";
  public string BgrColor => "dark gray";
}
```

I can construct a tracking factory that simply tracks objects it creates:

```
public class TrackingThemeFactory
{
  private readonly List<WeakReference<ITheme>> themes = new();

  public ITheme CreateTheme(bool dark)
  {
    ITheme theme = dark ? new DarkTheme() : new LightTheme();
    themes.Add(new WeakReference<ITheme>(theme));
    return theme;
  }

  public string Info
  {
    get
    {
      var sb = new StringBuilder();
      foreach (var reference in themes)
      {
        if (reference.TryGetTarget(out var theme))
        {
          bool dark = theme is DarkTheme;
          sb.Append(dark ? "Dark" : "Light");
          sb.AppendLine(" theme");
        }
      }
      return sb.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

If, however, I want to replace every constructed instance, I end up having to create a type with an extra level of indirection

```
public class Ref<T> where T : class
{
  public T Value;

  public Ref(T value)
  {
    Value = value;
  }
}
```

To be used in

```
public class ReplaceableThemeFactory
{
  private readonly List<WeakReference<Ref<ITheme>>> themes
    = new();

  private ITheme createThemeImpl(bool dark)
  {
    return dark ? new DarkTheme() : new LightTheme();
  }

  public Ref<ITheme> CreateTheme(bool dark)
  {
    var r = new Ref<ITheme>(createThemeImpl(dark));
    themes.Add(new(r));
    return r;
  }

  public void ReplaceTheme(bool dark)
  {
    foreach (var wr in themes)
    {
      if (wr.TryGetTarget(out var reference))
      {
        reference.Value = createThemeImpl(dark);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This does in fact work:

```
var factory2 = new ReplaceableThemeFactory();
var magicTheme = factory2.CreateTheme(true);
Console.WriteLine(magicTheme.Value.BgrColor); // dark gray
factory2.ReplaceTheme(false);
Console.WriteLine(magicTheme.Value.BgrColor); // white
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: you could have an `IndirectTheme : Ref<ITheme>, ITheme` and add a getter that does the `.Value` inside the getter? i.e. `string ITheme.TextColor => Value.TextColor; string ITheme.BgrColor => Value.BgrColor;` ? now your wrapper *is also* the theme, at least to the caller

Comment: Is it actually a business requirement to know how many active references there are to an object, or is it a debugging concern? If its the later, you have created a lot of subsequent issues for a problem that can potentially be solved other ways

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to replace an object in all (unknown) storage locations, so you are on the right track when you try to find a structure, where you know all storage locations of the object to be replaced -> indirection is your friend. Whether it's better to redirect the entire object reference or to implement a wrapper and redirect each method depends on the details of your use case I guess.

Comment: Why are you using an interface? You could just have an object `Theme` and initialize the properties to their respective value. Using overloads of getters for simple values is bad practice.

Comment: Also, not the existence of [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).